# TP-link 300M extender no connectivity

Tags: wifi-configuration

I recently bought a range extender and now I can't connect to the internet with some devices. I can connect to the network but I can't access the internet. My phone works but two laptops(windows 8 and Ubuntu) don't. Does anybody know the problem

Edit: I can't connect to any IPs in the network, my router is a dlink dir-615

Edit 2: when I connect to the extender directly over Ethernet I get a connection

Edit 3: I tried giving the extender a static IP and enabling dhcp but it didn't work either.

Edit 4: the model is 850RE

Comment: What model is it? Did you follow the installation instructions? Have you checked for a firmware update? Have you called tech support?

Comment: The model is 850RE and I did all of those things except calling techsupport, because i wanted to ask here first. Techsupport hasn't helped me before but stackexchange did.